# How to insert multiple numpy arrays into another numpy array at different indices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let’s say we have 4 numpy array A B,C and D, like following:

```
A = np.array([11,22,33,44,55,66,77])
B = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
C = np.array([6,7,8,9])
D = np.array([10,11])
```

I want to insert arrays B, C and D into array A. I have been given a list of indices of array A for where to insert the arrays B,C and D

```
idx = [1,3,5]
```

i.e. Array B should be inserted after A[1], array C inserted after A[3] and array D after A[5]

The expected output is something like this:

```
Out = ([11,22,1,2,3,4,5,33,44,6,7,8,9,55,66,10,11,77])
```

I have tried using the `np.insert` but it does not produce the required output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `np.insert` doesn't work because the arrays differ in size.  Well it should work with multiple inserts.  But since you are starting with lists, list insert will be simpler, and faster.

```
In [150]: A = ([11,22,33,44,55,66,77])
     ...: B = ([1,2,3,4,5])
     ...: C = ([6,7,8,9])
     ...: D = ([10,11])
```

Start from the end; that way the size increase won't mess up the indexing:

```
In [160]: A[6:6]=D
In [161]: A
Out[161]: [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 10, 11, 77]

In [162]: A[4:4]=C
In [163]: A[2:2]=B

In [164]: A
Out[164]: [11, 22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 33, 44, 6, 7, 8, 9, 55, 66, 10, 11, 77]
```

Here's a way of using one insert:

```
In [173]: A = np.array([11,22,33,44,55,66,77])

In [174]: idx = np.array([1,3,5]).repeat((len(B),len(C),len(D)))+1    
In [175]: idx
Out[175]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6])

In [176]: np.insert(A,idx, np.hstack((B,C,D)))
Out[176]: 
array([11, 22,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 33, 44,  6,  7,  8,  9, 55, 66, 10, 11,
       77])
```

The insert `idx` needs to match the `values` array in size.

Your `[1,3,5]` are 'insert after' values.  Both list and `insert` use 'insert before', hence the '+1' adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([11,22,33,44,55,66,77])
B = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
C = np.array([6,7,8,9])
D = np.array([10,11])
idx = [1,3,5]

# initialize the output array with A
Out = A.copy()

# loop through the indices in reverse order and concatenate the arrays
for i in reversed(idx):
    if i == idx[-1]:
        Out = np.concatenate((Out[:i+1], D, Out[i+1:]))
    elif i == idx[-2]:
        Out = np.concatenate((Out[:i+1], C, Out[i+1:]))
    else:
        Out = np.concatenate((Out[:i+1], B, Out[i+1:]))

print(Out)
```

Comment: you could make a list of tuples with `idx` and `B, C, D` to simplify the loop

Comment: ofc, great suggestion!